# UIView autoresizing issue when programmatically loaded

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, autoresize, autoresizingmask

I have added a UIView in the xib with an UIImage and UILabel.I have set the autoresizing in the xib itself.I am presenting this view to animate from the bottom to the centre,where i adjust the final frame after animation,but the view has no effect of autoresizing.

Comment: can you provide code what you have done so far?